# $inject in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I have problem with inject a services to my controller. Below is the code and the result of this actions.

**user.service.js:**

```
class UsersService{
    constructor(){}
    usersServiceFn () {
        return {
            name: 'TEST'
        };
    };
}
export default UsersService;
```

**users.jsp:**

```
import UsersService from './users.service';

export default app => {
  app.factory('users', UsersService);

  if (ENVIRONMENT === 'test') {
    require('./users.test.js');
  }
}
```

**service.js:**

```
import usersService from './users/users';

export default app => {
  INCLUDE_ALL_MODULES([usersService], app);
}
```

**index.js:**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularUIRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import appComponents from './components/components.js';
import commonComponents from './common/components.js';
import appServices from './services/services.js';
import appConfiguration from './app.config';

// Single Style Entry Point
import './index.scss';

if (ENVIRONMENT === 'test') {
  console.log('ENV:', ENVIRONMENT);
  require('angular-mocks/angular-mocks');
}

const app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
appComponents(app);
commonComponents(app);
appServices(app);
```

**home.controller.js:**

```
 class HomeController {

        constructor($scope, $http, usersService) {
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.$http = $http;
            this.usersService = usersService;
            this.$scope.persons = null;
            this.name = 'home';
            this.$scope.surname ='ZZZZZZ';
            this.$scope.randomNumb = Math.random();
            this.initRecords();
            this.range();
            this.watchText();
        }

   /..../    


    }
    HomeController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'usersService'];
    export default HomeController;
```

**And the result:**

[image]

Im trying but I don't know where is the problem.

**structure: ** 
[image]

Comment: please provide code where you register services

Comment: @Vitalii You mean users.jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
app.factory('users', UsersService);
```

To

```
app.factory('usersService', UsersService);
```

Comment: It generated the same problems. The general name of service is in service.js ? so probably it doesn't matter how we call it in users.jsp ?

Comment: @RuntimeException name in registration area (app.factory('some_name')) should be the same as in $inject array. Check your code to be sure your factory really registered in app module.